# jquery toggle transparent cover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have small problem with making a transparent div covering another div. I need the transparent div to appear over another div when the user hovers the mouse over the original div. I managed to make the transparent div appear over the first one but when the mouse leaves the transparent div stays over. I have a pretty good idea why is this happening, the cover is on the top of the first div and jquery can`t detect anymore if the mouse left the original div, I tried this two versions

```
$("#top_content").hover(function(){
    $("#top_cover").css("opacity","0.35"); 
}, function(){
    $("#top_cover").css("display","0"); 
});

$("#top_cover").hover(function(){
    $("#top_cover").css("opacity","0.35"); 
}, function(){
    $("#top_cover").css("display","0"); 
});
```

Both work with adding the cover, but neither with removing it. And here is the jsfidle
http://jsfiddle.net/HjW53/

EDIT I can`t believe how dumb I am, I started with display none/block but then gone to opacity solution and forgot to change display to opacity. Thank you for the solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared something wrong in your second statement. Here is the easiest fix. Just reset the `opacity` value again, instead of display.

#### http://jsfiddle.net/HjW53/4/

```
$("#top_content").hover(function(){
    $("#top_cover").css("opacity","0.35"); 
}, function(){
    $("#top_cover").css("opacity","0"); 
});
```

The problem with using `display:none` or `0` is that it will be `hidden` from the `DOM`, so you will never be able to `hover` again after the first fire.

Answer (score 2):

No need for scripting at all..

just add this css rule

```
#top_content:hover #top_cover{
    opacity:0.35;
}
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/HjW53/5/

---

The actual error on your code though was not that jquery could not detect the overlap.
Since the `#top_cover` is a child of `#top_content` it will always trigger hover events on all its parents.. (*besides the `opacity` does not affect the hover events..*) so if it worked to set the opacity it would work with unsetting it..

The problem was with the `"display","0"`

It should either be `"display","none"` (*but it would only work the first time*) or use the same property on both cases, so `"opacity","0"`

Comment: This is definitely the quicker solution compared to mine. Just tried to fix the existing problem :-P Nice job @Gaby. Either of our solutions work, but if you have a `CSS` solution instead of a `JS` one, your page will render quicker.

Answer (score -1):

`$("#top_cover").css("display","0");` seems to not work, I replaced the `0` by `none` and it worked like a charm.

Here's the updated version:

```
$("#top_content").hover(function(){
    $("#top_cover").css("opacity","0.35"); 
}, function(){
    $("#top_cover").css("display","none"); 
});
```

Comment: If you add a `display:none;` it will not reactivate again, because it is hidden from the `DOM`